# Excel VBA : SQL query handles error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sql

I have SQL that I can use in Excel 2013 to get the info from the Access database and it works using the SQL directly in a connection, but now I want to run it from VBA instead so I can use some variables in the SQL.

I found this link, modified it and it works on some simpler SQL statements, but not on others.

[Execute SQL Query with VBA and fill sheet with data](https://superuser.com/questions/813077/execute-sql-query-with-vba-and-fill-sheet-with-data)

I get an error:

> Run Time error -2147217883 (80040e25) Row Handles must all be released before new ones can be obtained.

I have searched a lot on this error and tried different things, but obviously don't understand. I know the SQL is long/complex, but it works in Access and Excel directly.

Here is current code:

```
Sub Get_SQLData()
'modified from from https://superuser.com/questions/813077/execute-sql-query-with-vba-and-fill-sheet-with-data
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String

strFile = "C:\mydb.accdb"

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strFile

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strCon

'JAJ set my SQL RAW first
strSQL = "SELECT RAWDATA_Incidents.ID, RAWDATA_Incidents.[Incident Number], RAWDATA_Incidents.[Categorization Tier 1], RAWDATA_Incidents.[Categorization Tier 2], RAWDATA_Incidents.[Categorization Tier 3], RAWDATA_Incidents.Priority, RAWDATA_Incidents.Urgency, RAWDATA_Incidents.Impact, RAWDATA_Incidents.[Reported Date], RAWDATA_Incidents.[Service Type], RAWDATA_Incidents.[Closure Product Category Tier1], RAWDATA_Incidents.[Closure Product Category Tier2], RAWDATA_Incidents.[Closure Product Category Tier3], ClosureProductName.ClosureProductName, RAWDATA_Incidents.Status, RAWDATA_Incidents.[Closed Date], RAWDATA_Incidents.[Product Name], OpsCatTreeFaultMode.FaultMode, BusinessService.MMServiceID, ([RAWDATA_Incidents]![Closed Date]-[RAWDATA_Incidents]![Reported Date])*1440 AS Expr2, IIf([RAWDATA_Incidents]![Priority]='Critical' Or [RAWDATA_Incidents]![Priority]='High',788,394) AS Expr3, BusinessService.Name, BSDependsOnAC.MMServiceID, CI.CIName, AccessChannel.Name, BusinessService.ID " _
    & "FROM OpsCatTreeFaultMode INNER JOIN (RAWDATA_Incidents INNER JOIN (CI INNER JOIN ((ITSystemService INNER JOIN (BusinessService INNER JOIN ((AccessChannel INNER JOIN ACDependsOnITSS ON AccessChannel.ACID = ACDependsOnITSS.ACID.Value) INNER JOIN BSDependsOnAC ON AccessChannel.ACID = BSDependsOnAC.ACID.Value) ON BusinessService.ID = BSDependsOnAC.MMServiceID.Value) ON (ITSystemService.ITSSID = ACDependsOnITSS.ITSSID.Value) AND (ITSystemService.ITSSID = ACDependsOnITSS.ITSSID.Value)) INNER JOIN ClosureProductName ON ITSystemService.ITSSID = ClosureProductName.ITSS.Value) ON CI.CIID = ITSystemService.CIID) ON RAWDATA_Incidents.[Closure Product Name] = ClosureProductName.ClosureProductName) ON OpsCatTreeFaultMode.OpsCatTreeName = RAWDATA_Incidents.[Categorization Tier 3]"

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")
rs.activeconnection = cn

rs.Open strSQL

Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs     ' fails here  - gives handles error.

rs.Close
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How long until the error message is thrown? Could it be the query is timing out?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the line it fails on and add a watch to RS, is RS actually populated with expected data at that time?

Comment: you could `rs.requery` after `rs.Open strSQL` although I'm not confident it will help

Comment: What version of excel and how much data might come back

Comment: To answer all points so far. Using Access and Excel 2013. Error is thrown in 10 seconds (same time query takes to run during a refresh in excel normally). Query actually takes longer to run in access (15 sec). Tried rs.requery - no change. Query as stated returns 66040 rows, 26 columns. I tried reducing with a where clause to where it only returns 93 rows, still fails. I added breakpont - I see that it is returning field names, don;t know how to see if it is returning values. Thanks to all so far, any other thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Your script is hugely complex... Any way, what happens if you remove the alias columns? Does it help then?

Comment: I found [an answer in StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13142222/4519059), is that helpful? ;).

Comment: To decide is it the database or the script change the select to "SELECT top 25 RAWDATA_Incidents.ID,...  This will limit it to the first 25 entries. If this does not work, then you have a problem with your syntax or coding. If it works, then increase the top size. and try again until find issue.

Comment: I thought Excel 2013 had only 65,536 rows? In Access I don't think there is a limit. Could this be your problem?

Comment: Ah, I just saw something from shA.t. That's exactly what I was thinking, Stack Overflow, it's when you run out of memory -- caused by infinite loops and things like that, but in your case it's your exceeding 65,000 rows of data.

Comment: Sorry for the extra comments. I just read your comment about "tried 93 rows" but still fails. I think you will still get a Stack Overflow error if you access a database from Excel 2013 of over the 65,000+ threshold. You are still accessing more than what's allowed although you are only retrieving 93 or whatever small amount of records. To try this theory, you need to create a smaller file with a record set that doesn't exceed 65K and test it (don't fake it with LIMIT in query create a separate file).

Comment: Have you considered having your SQL query as the source of a Pivot Table? This always worked for me with thooousands of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have some redundancies:

```
Sub Get_SQLData()

Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String

strFile = "C:\mydb.accdb"
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strFile
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strCon  

'JAJ set my SQL RAW first 
strSQL = "..."

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")
rs.activeconnection = cn
rs.Open strSQL

Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs     ' fails here  - gives handles error.
rs.Close
cn.Close

Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Your problem begins here:

`rs.activeconnection = cn`

You've stated

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strCon
```

You are pointing with rs, to an object already created and opened. Instead instantiate a new connection rather than trying to clone it. You are pointing to an object here.